# calculating the probability in Gambler's ruin problem such that the player does not go broke or hit the target.

Tags: probability

This is from Rosenthal's First Look at Rigorous Probability Theory Excercise 7.4.5 and I think one could easily solve this problem after learning Martingale, but the problem is that I haven't studied that part yet.

Suppose $0<a<c$ and let $t_{0}$=inf{$n\geq0$;$X_{n}=0$} and $t_{c}$=inf{$n\geq 0$;$X_{n}=c$} be the first hitting time of 0 and c respectively.

Let $B_{n}$=Pr(min($t_{0}$, $t_{c}$)>n) be the probability that the player's fortune has not hit 0 or c by time n.
(a) Find any explicit, simple expression $G_{n}$ such that $B_{n}$<$G_{n}$ for all n and such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}$$G_{n}$=0
(b) Find any explicit, simple expression $A_{n}$ such that $B_{n}$>$A_{n}$>0 for all n

For (a), I have tried to use Markov's inequality so that $P\leq \Pr(\min(t_{0}, t_{c})/n)$ but cannot proceed from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be in the same probability course as @Siri, who asked the same question after you [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2531623/gamblers-ruin-model/2531757?noredirect=1#comment5228178_2531757). I posted an answer there.